# Processing a String and replacing al URL's with working links via Java

Tags: java, url, hyperlink, anchor, transform

How would I transform a text like the following or any other text containing an URL (http ftp etc)

> Go to this link http://www.google.com (ofc stack overflow already does this, on my website this is just plain text);

Into this

> Go to this link `<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>`

I've come up with this method

```
public String transformURLIntoLinks(String text){
    String urlValidationRegex = "(https?|ftp)://(www\\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\\d+)?)([/?:].*)?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlValidationRegex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()){
        String found =m.group(1); //this String is only made of the http or ftp (just the first part of the link)
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href='"+found+"'>"+found+"</a>"); // the result would be <a href="http">"http"</a>
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The problem is the regexes i've tried match only the first part("http" or "ftp").

My output becomes: `Go to this link <a href='http'>http</a>`

It should be this

`Go to this link <a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>`

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a coding service. If you've tried something yourself that did not work, come back and ask for help. But don't ask us to solve your work.

Comment: Simple: `public String transformURLIntoLinks(String text){
    return "Go to this link <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">www.google.com</a>";
}`

Comment: It must transform any text containing an URL to the same text containing the anchor of the url.

Comment: I've reworded the question and provided an attempted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String transformURLIntoLinks(String text){
String urlValidationRegex = "(https?|ftp)://(www\\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\\d+)?)([/?:].*)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlValidationRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String found =m.group(0); 
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href='"+found+"'>"+found+"</a>"); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
return sb.toString();
   }
```

m.group(1) was the mistake. m.group(0) works.
This will transform any URL found in the text into an anchor.

Comment: This solution doesn`t work for cases where there are multiple links in the string.