# Replace URL in text with href (in Java)

Tags: java, regex, href

I have to tranform url's entered in plain text into html hrefs and I want to find multiple urls.

This:
    `Hi here is a link for you: http://www.google.com. Hope it works.`

Will become:
    `Hi here is a link for you: <a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>. Hope it works.`

Found this code:

```
public String transformURLIntoLinks(String text){
String urlValidationRegex = "(https?|ftp)://(www\\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\\d+)?)([/?:].*)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlValidationRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String found =m.group(0); 
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href='"+found+"'>"+found+"</a>"); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
return sb.toString();
}
```

Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704902

And it works perfectly. For all urls properly prefixed with `http`.
But I also want to find url's starting with just `www`.

Can anyone that knows his regex help me out?

Comment: Try to begin your regex with ```(?:(https?|ftp):\/\/)?``` and it will match with url starting with just ```www```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Make the `(https?|ftp)://` part optional. This is done by adding a question mark `?`. So it will be `((https?|ftp)://)?`</strike>

Use this RegEx:

```regex
\b((https?|ftp):\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)*(?:\/|\b)
```

Escape Java escape character (\):

```regex
\\b((https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{2,256}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\\b(\\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)*(?:\\/|\\b)
```

### Examples

#### Example 1 (with protocol, in sentence)

[image: Example 1]

#### Example 2 (without protocol, in sentence)

[image: Example 2]

Comment: The text I am transforming is not only urls. Tried implementing your code but it turned everything in my text into hrefs
This: `Hi here's a link for you
www.google.com
Take care!`
Turned into:
`<a href='Hi here's'>Hi here's</a><a href=' a link'> a link</a><a href=' for you'> for you</a><a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a><a href='Take care!'>Take care!</a>`

Comment: @Anders I've edited my answer. I did not know it should take a link from a sentence. It should now be working.

Comment: Work like a charm. Added some code that adds the protocol and it's all set. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the www optinnal by surrounding.
You case try this:

```
  final String urlValidationRegex = "(https?|ftp)://(www\\d?)?(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\\d+)?)([/?:].*)?"
```

Comment: That is not what OP is asking for. He want's to be able to omit the protocol, not the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following pattern.

> ((https?|ftp)://)?(www\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\d+)?)([/?:].*)?

The updated code will be

```
public String transformURLIntoLinks(String text){
String urlValidationRegex = "((https?|ftp)://)?(www\\d?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\:|.)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|(\\d+)?)([/?:].*)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlValidationRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String found =m.group(0); 
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a href='"+found+"'>"+found+"</a>"); 
}
m.appendTail(sb);
return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why use `(something|)` when you can just do `(something)?`?

Comment: Yes, Using a meta-character is always better. Updated the post, Thanks.